# Configuring default character encoding in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I have a web service built with Grails 3 that I would like to have return characters in UTF-8 by default.

If I have a controller method end with something like

```
render(text: someResponse, encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

it works how I would want it to. But, if it ends with

```
render(text: someResponse)
```

it defaults to 'charset=ISO-8859-1'

My application.yml file does contain the following block that seems like it should be setting the default encoding to UTF-8 but clearly it isn't working.

```
grails:
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
```

What do I need to set in my app's configuration to get UTF-8 by default when render is called?

Comment: what do you use as web server? tomcat?